# postmapping with validated class

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working with the actuator sample which comes with springboot. However, there is a method `olleh` that I really don't know how to use it, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-actuator/src/main/java/sample/actuator/SampleController.java#L49) is the source code of the controller. And the following the is a snippet of the code that I don't understand.

```
@PostMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> olleh(@Validated Message message) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("message", message.getValue());
    model.put("title", "Hello Home");
    model.put("date", new Date());
    return model;
}
```

It looks to me like I need to make a post request to `http://localhost:8080/`, however, looks like the input is a Message class, and then it will create a dictionary and return it to the user as JSON?

Can anyone share with me how to post a Java object?

---

Update1: I tried techtabu's answer, however, it is returning 400 complaining that the message object we posted is not valid. Any idea why this is happening? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You actually has to make POST request with JSON object equivalent to the Message class. You can make something like,

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/' --header "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{
    "value" : "This is my message"
}'
```

Spring MVC knows how to convert it to Message Object which has only one field `value`. The method in the controller, will create a `Map` using your message and some other fields, and return it again as a JSON object.

Comment: can you take a look at the update of my question, I think it is close but still not working.